# CustomLoginModule for Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

The system we are building needs authentication with Active Directory and
we need to get some extra attribute values such as displayName, setting it UserIndentity object.

Current LDAPLoginModule can do authentication, but can not collect extra attributes. So we are considering to make CustomLoginModule do the above, from scratch or by extending existing LDAPLoginModule. Is there any sample code or guide to perform AD authentication and search?

To configure CustomLoginModule, we need to add parameters in 
authenticationConfig.xml. I am not sure how we can get parameter values from CustomLoginModule.

Any help or sample code would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Active Directory with WebSphere (either full or Liberty profile) then the required attributes may be available via the WAS user identity object. 
You can find this out by enabling WAS trace and see the object in the trace output.

The trace to use:

> *=info:com.ibm.ws.security.*=all:com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.security.*=all:ibm.com.worklight.*=all